# Where to set aws access/secret key for kube-up.sh to work correctly in Kubernetes (aws)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am trying to setup a Kubernetes cluster on my AWS account using the `kube-up.sh` setup script that is bundled with kubernetes source at kubernetes/cluster/kube-up.sh

But when I ran kube-up.sh I am getting the following error:

```
pranjal:~/go/src/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/cluster$ ./kube-up.sh
Starting cluster using os distro: ubuntu
Starting cluster using provider: aws
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling kube-up
Uploading to Amazon S3
Creating kubernetes-staging-6b790c161af2b2c39939b542c73b775a
make_bucket failed: s3://kubernetes-staging-6b790c161af2b2c39939b542c73b775
```

I am sure that my the tool is not able to read my AWS Access Key and Secret. I stored it in .aws/config. I am not sure where I should set it for it to be able to read it correctly and work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of searching I figured out a solution to the problem.

A lot of the AWS configuration goes into the [config-default.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/aws/config-default.sh) file. However there is no option to set the Access Key ID, Secret Access Key there (which might make some sense as cluster/aws/config-default.sh file is a part of the source code and the credentials should be saved somewhere else, at a safer place)

I realized after seeing the kubernetes/cluster/aws/util.sh source code that kubernetes actually calls the **aws** command line tool internally to make changes to AWS infrastructure.

So having the AWS command line tool installed and configured correctly will do the job of solving this problem.

Once I issued the following command:

```
aws configure
```

and answered prompts for entering ID/Key it saved these values to this file:

```
~/.aws/credentials
```

See details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)

This solved my problem and kube-up.sh worked perfectly after I did this.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to populate environment variables ...  put following commands into a file xxxxx

```
export     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(cat ${AWS_ACCOUNT_CONFIGDIR}/id)
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(cat ${AWS_ACCOUNT_CONFIGDIR}/key)
```

then source that file prior to calling kube-up.sh

```
source xxxxx
kube-up.sh
```

aws first looks at above pair of env vars prior to probing

```
~/.aws/credentials
```

which I find makes it easier to toggle between various aws accounts